# Im trying to change image on chrome://newtab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, tampermonkey

How do I fix the error? If I paste the code in the dev console it works but if I run it the image won't change unless I do stop(); which then breaks the search bar and background

CODE

```js
document.getElementById('hplogo').src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/63/IMG_%28business%29.svg/1280px-IMG_%28business%29.svg.png";
```

```html
<div class="" id="lga" style="height: 250px;"><img alt="Google" height="92" id="hplogo" src="/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" width="272" title="Google" style="padding-top: 115px;"><div id="logo-sub"></div></div>
```

ERROR

```html
VM13104:2 TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at Window.eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:479), <anonymous>:15:38)
    at <anonymous>:2:479
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:479), <anonymous>:2:1)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:479), <anonymous>:3:3)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:479), <anonymous>:16:6)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:479), <anonymous>:16:50)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:479
    at Object.c [as F_c] (<anonymous>:2:324)
    at Object.E_u (<anonymous>:3:143)
```

Comment: Chrome 61 and newer no longer run content scripts on the default new tab page, see [chrome content scripts and newtab](//stackoverflow.com/a/45659562)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thats why I have tampermonkey I am able to remove the recent tabs menu with a error of null but thats not the issue.

Comment: Tampermonkey can't run its content scripts and your userscripts for the same reason in Chrome 61 and newer.